# msbuild conditon ignored when creating an UWP project

Tags: uwp, msbuild, visual-studio-2022

Recently I realized that msbuild behaves somehow different when it parses a blank uwp project. msbuild ignores conditions in uwp projects, which messes up our code.

The repro is simple

- Open visual studio 2022
- Create a "Blank App (Universal Windows)"
- Open the csproj with a text editor
- Insert this code at the very end just before the last `<import>` statement

```cs
  <ItemGroup Condition="''=='Do never include this here'">
    <PackageReference Include="I am included, hahaha. I ignore your condition" Version="16.7" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

- Build the solution

The output should be something like

> NU1101: Unable to find package I am included, hahaha. I ignore your condition. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org

this repro does correctly work on C# console apps but fails for UWP apps. Does anyone have hints why or whether this is a known bug? I couldn't find anything. But ignoring conditions looks very odd to me.

Also: I've tried putting the condition into the `PackageReference`, same effect, ignored condition and included the reference.

Comment: I added the PackageReference in the Blank App (Universal Windows) project, and the build didn't encounter any errors.

Comment: @PengGe can you check the target version? We are currently pinned  to `<TargetPlatformVersion Condition=" '$(TargetPlatformVersion)' == '' ">10.0.19041.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>`

Comment: Hi Samuel, any update of this issue, have you checked the answer I posted? :)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

[Reproduce and Solve.gif](https://testbowman.blob.core.windows.net/test/UWP.gif)

**Original Answer:**

After I copy the item group section you shared to my UWP .csproj file, I am able to reproduce your issue with no problem:

[image]

I can make the issue disappear via this:

```
  <ItemGroup Condition="'' == 'Do never include this here'">
    <PackageReference Include="I am included, hahaha. I ignore your condition" Version="16.7" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

[image]

The only difference is between single quote(') and double equals(==) need to have a space.

And this is what the official document told us:

[ItemGroup element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/itemgroup-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022)

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work on 17.4.4. I pulled UWP version to the highest number (windows 11 Build 22000 just in case). Did not work. I copied the item group from your snippet -> no effect.

Comment: @Samuel My VS is Microsoft Visual Studio Community 17.4.4, are you using the same version as me?

Comment: @Samuel I tested it again, I found I can still reproduce the issue via the content you provided, and make the issue disappear via adding two space. I can reproduce and solve the above situation very stably. I think your situation may not only caused by this but also caused by other reasons, please try to repair the VS tools via vs installer and follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75247363/visual-studio-2022-is-opening-files-from-the-call-stack-and-search-window-in-the/75253649#75253649) to reset the environment settings and settings sync.

Comment: @Samuel I updated a gif of the steps on my side, you can see that I reproduce and solve the issue very stably on my side. If I do something wrong, please feel free to let me know. :)

Comment: @Samuel No matter what caused this issue, you can report this to the product group via this: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report .

Comment: Can you provide the test project to reproduce this on my machine? I am on Visual Studio Professional 17.4.