# Visual Studio 2022 is opening files from the call stack and search window in the bottom pane

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-debugging

I'm debugging a C# ASP.NET app.  When I double click on an item in the call stack it's opening the file in the bottom pane of Visual Studio 2022.  I know how to change where all these persistent windows like (Call Stack, Breakpoints, etc.) open, but I can't figure out how to change where files get opened in the call stack.  I'd like them to open above, in the main pane where my other code is located.  I currently have to drag them from the bottom pane to the main pane.

I just noticed that the search window is doing the same...

I'm running:

```
 Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022
Version 17.2.8
VisualStudio.17.Release.LTSC.17.2/17.2.8+32901.213
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084

Installed Version: Professional

Visual C++ 2022   00476-80000-00000-AA770
Microsoft Visual C++ 2022

.NET Core Debugging with WSL   1.0
.NET Core Debugging with WSL

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019   17.2.393.26812
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.2.393.26812
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   17.2.393.26812
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

C# Tools   4.2.0-4.22281.5+8d3180e5f00d42f0f0295165f756f368f0cbfa44
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

NuGet Package Manager   6.2.1
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

Razor (ASP.NET Core)   17.0.0.2218101+885a343b00bcab620a90c1550c37dafd730ce984
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

SQL Server Data Tools   17.0.62204.01010
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Test Adapter for Boost.Test   1.0
Enables Visual Studio's testing tools with unit tests written for Boost.Test.  The use terms and Third Party Notices are available in the extension installation directory.

Test Adapter for Google Test   1.0
Enables Visual Studio's testing tools with unit tests written for Google Test.  The use terms and Third Party Notices are available in the extension installation directory.

TypeScript Tools   17.0.10418.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   4.2.0-4.22281.5+8d3180e5f00d42f0f0295165f756f368f0cbfa44
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools   17.1.0-beta.22329.1+702b8e77f5fbfe21e6743324c1750503e02f182d
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2
AI-assisted development for Visual Studio.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my research, I think the default layout of clicking the code line in the Call Stack windows will not show in the bottom pane of Visual Studio 2022.

I think  this situation comes from some changes based on the default settings or some extensions you installed.

First of all, please make sure there isn't any extension that can affect the layout of windows.

Second, you can follow the below steps to reset the settings of the layout or reset the settings of the total language environment collection settings:

Reset the layout settings:

[image]

Reset the language environment collection settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And to make sure not effected by the settings of the async user's settings, please [turn off the user settings async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/synchronized-settings-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#turn-off-synchronized-settings-on-a-particular-computer):

[image][7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AiKm.png)

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's very comprehensive. I'll make sure and try that when I'm next at my work computer.  Thanks!  This happened to me a couple years ago at my previous job with a different computer and it seemed to just "fix itself " eventually.

Comment: @Eric Hi Eric, any update of this issue? By the way, you can also try to repair VS via vs tool Installer. :)

Comment: I followed your steps and it fixed my issues.  Not sure if I needed to do all of them.